# How to actually merge/join the internal storage and external SD card!

Tags: sd-card

I have a 30 Gig external SD card in my LG 9 phone. I am trying to merge/join the SD card with the internal storage so when i save ANYTHING on my phone whether it be an app (including updates), a song, a video, a picture, system updates, etc. I want it all to know how to save to my SD card automatically without setting up directories or using a "transfer file to SD card" app.

Comment: Well, apart from system files and apps, you can install any third-party file sync app, and synchronize both SD cards.

Comment: This is a feature that is being introduced in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow). Unless you already have that version of Android, you'll have to make do with more cumbersome hacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try link2sd, use the first partition on SD as internal storage.

I had many issues with link2sd, mostly related to app failing installation/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Xposed module [XInternalSD](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinternalsd). It will change the default save path of all of your apps to the external SD card. It can be enabled for all apps or on a per-app basis. As far as I know there is no way to accomplish this without root. Although technically there is no way to "merge" the internal and external memory; they are mounted at different points on boot. But this is probably the best solution for what you want to do.

App2SD (available in the Play Store) is another option. It is updated frequently and includes multiple methods of linking a 2nd partition (standard root, init.d and su.d) which offers good performance especially if you have SuperSU and can use su.d mode. However it requires more configuration and tweaking than the XInternalSD module.

Stay away from Link2SD. It hasn't been updated in a long time and appears to be a dead project. It does not include all the helpful tools and multiple methods of App2SD either. I would not recommend using it except maybe on very old devices.

Comment: Just FYR, you can patch the boot and force mount external SD card to somewhere in the internal memory, acting as if it's part of internal.